# Dicionário Python - Contagem de Palavras mais frequentes

Tags: python, funções, dicionário

boa noite.

Estou estudando dicionários, desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo para contabilização de palavras em artigos contidos em arquivos TXT's e exibição de palavras mais frequentes, porém, não estou conseguindo realizar a remoção de preposições na contagem, sendo assim,  a mesma se torna ineficaz, pois sempre encontro palavras como ( A, até, de, o, e ...)

Obs: consegui remover pontuações, porém, não está funcionando para caracteres e palavras.

```
def converte_texto(texto):

    pontuacao = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?', '"','(', ')','DE','A','a','para','do','o','O','Em','em']    
    novo_texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
    lista = novo_texto.split()
    return lista

def palavras(texto):

    contagem = dict()
    for palavra in texto :
        contagem[palavra] = contagem.get(palavra, 0) + 1
    return contagem

def mais_comum(texto):

    frequencias = texto.values()
    maior = max(frequencias)

    palavras = []
    for chave in texto:
        if texto[chave] == maior:
           palavras.append(chave)

    return (palavras, maior)

def palavras_mais_frequentes(texto, min_vezes):

    resultado = []
    fim = False

    while not fim :
        temp = mais_comum( texto )  
        if temp[1] >= min_vezes :      
            resultado.append(temp)
            for palavra in temp[0]:
                del( texto[ palavra ] )
        else :
            fim = True
    return resultado


def abrir_arquivo(nome):

    pontuacao = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?', '"','(', ')','DE','A','a','para','do','o','O','Em','em']   
    texto = open(nome, 'r') 
    texto = texto.read()
    texto_final = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
    lista = texto_final.split()
    return lista


lista = abrir_arquivo('Novo Rodizio - G1.txt')
dicionario = palavras( lista )


print("Palavra Mais Comum Fonte - G1 : ", mais_comum( dicionario ) )
print( )
print("Palavras Mais Frequentes Fonte G1: ", palavras_mais_frequentes( dicionario, 10 ) )
print( )
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu código não funciona porque você está selecionando um caractere de cada vez e comparando ele com uma palavra de duas ou tres letras.

Você pode tentar transformar o texto em uma lista usando o metodo `split` e remover as palavras que quiser:

```
preposicoes = [...]
texto = "..."
palavras = texto.split()
for prep in preposicoes:
    palavras.remove(prep)
```